# getting this error while using if conditions in python.Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, if-statement

How to solve this issue, i am getting this while calling a function with if condition. I dont know where i am went wrong. Anyone please guide me to solve this.

```
    path = pd.read_csv("/home/volumata/Documents/Sangeetha/Analytics/saved-test-data/telecom_whole.csv")
    #print(orginal_telecom_whole)
orginal_telecom_80p_train, orginal_telecom_80p_test = train_test_split(path, test_size=0.20)

data =  orginal_telecom_80p_train

data = orginal_telecom_80p_test

def read_data(path, data):

    if data == 'orginal_telecom_80p_train':
        return(head_tail(data))
    elif data == 'orginal_telecom_80p_test':
        return(data_info_for_analysis(data))

    return data

    #name = input("path","data2","data1")

def head_tail(data):

    "Head of the data"

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_train.head(5))

    "Tail of the data"

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_train.tail(5))

def data_info_for_analysis(data):

    "Shape of the data"

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_test.shape)

    "data describe"

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_test.describe())

    "max & min value"

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_test.max())

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_test.min())

    "Checking the datatypes"

    print(orginal_telecom_80p_test.dtypes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_data(path, data)
```

getting this below error

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

If it is data == 'orginal_telecom_80p_train', it need to display first if condition part, if it is data == 'orginal_telecom_80p_test' it need to display second if condition.

My sample dataset

```
customerID  Date    gender  age region  SeniorCitizen   Partner Dependents  tenure  PhoneService    MultipleLines   InternetService OnlineSecurity  OnlineBackup    DeviceProtection    TechSupport StreamingTV StreamingMovies Contract    PaperlessBilling    PaymentMethod   MonthlyCharges  TotalCharges    Churn
9796-BPKIW  1/2/2008    Male    57  Northeast   1   No  No  8   Yes No  Fiber optic No  No  No  No  No  No  Month-to-month  Yes Credit card (automatic) 69.95   562.7   No
4298-OYIFC  1/4/2008    Male    50  South   0   Yes No  15  Yes Yes Fiber optic No  No  Yes Yes Yes Yes Month-to-month  Yes Electronic check    103.45  1539.8  No
9606-PBKBQ  1/6/2008    Male    85  Midwest 1   Yes No  32  Yes Yes Fiber optic No  No  No  No  No  Yes Month-to-month  Yes Electronic check    85  2642.05 Yes
1704-NRWYE  1/9/2008    Female  55  Midwest 1   No  No  9   Yes No  Fiber optic No  No  No  No  Yes No  Month-to-month  Yes Electronic check    80.85   751.65  Yes
9758-MFWGD  1/6/2008    Female  52  Northeast   1   Yes Yes 48  No  No  DSL No  Yes No  No  No  No  One year    No  Bank transfer (automatic)   29.9    1388.75 No
3777-XROBG  11/20/2012  Female  57  Northeast   0   Yes Yes 58  Yes No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  Two year    No  Credit card (automatic) 19.55   1079.65 No
5863-OOKCL  1/6/2008    Female  50  Midwest 0   No  No  10  Yes No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  Month-to-month  No  Mailed check    18.85   163.2   No
1766-GKNMI  1/6/2008    Male    53  Northeast   0   No  No  29  Yes Yes Fiber optic No  No  No  No  No  Yes Month-to-month  Yes Electronic check    84.9    2516.2  No
2592-YKDIF  1/6/2008    Female  78  Midwest 0   No  No  1   Yes No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  Month-to-month  No  Mailed check    20.35   20.35   No
```

Comment: Where? Which line?

Comment: What did you expect `if (data1) :` to mean?

Comment: If it is train data it should display first function if it is test data it should display below function. This is the sample code which i am trying for testing if condition

Comment: if train data comes it should perform train functions, if it is test data it should perform the corresponding functions'

Comment: could you provide a sample of your csv so one may be able to replicate the issue you face

Comment: i have given my sample dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the value of data1 and data2, so that condition would only check if data1 and data2 are not 0, you need to redesign the if condition as such and that should be based on how you decide data1/2 has test or train data.

Comment: How to design the if condition can you please suggest. My requirement is if train data comes it should do model budilding function like tat. if test data comes it should do predict functions